# Kernel cannot see my AX500 Wi-Fi card

Tags: wireless, kernel, 21.04, xps

I managed to have Wi-Fi enabled and working for some weeks on my Dell XPS 9500 first with Ubuntu 20.04 with a custom kernel, and then for some days after upgrading to Ubuntu 21.04/hirsute with the generic kernel.

I am currently running the kernel `5.11.0-31-generic`

My Wi-Fi card does not show up anymore, and it is not listed with `lspci`.

Expected `lspci` output:

```
6c:00.0 Network controller [0280] Qualcomm Device [17cb:1101] (rev 01)
Subsystem Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device [1a56:a501]
```

From the logs, the kernel does not seem to see my PCI card:

Correct log (before the issue):

```
Aug 17 14:44:58 XXX kernel: [    0.375432] pci 0000:6c:00.0: [17cb:1101] type 00 class 0x028000
Aug 17 14:44:58 XXX kernel: [    0.375452] pci 0000:6c:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xb4200000-0xb42fffff 64bit]
Aug 17 14:44:58 XXX kernel: [    0.375568] pci 0000:6c:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
Aug 17 14:44:58 XXX kernel: [    0.375628] pci 0000:6c:00.0: 4.000 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth, limited by 5.0 GT/s PCIe x1 link at 0000:00:1c.5 (capable of 7.876 Gb/s with 8.0 GT/s PCIe x1 link)
```

`17cb:1101` being the VID/PID of my card: https://www.pcilookup.com/?ven=17cb&dev=1101&action=submit

I tried to switch off my computer for some time but the kernel still can´t see my card.

Any idea of what could cause this issue ?

BR.

**Edit:**

After shuting down and unpluging the computer for a longer period, Wi-Fi is working well again.
The card was probably in a unstable state.
I am wondering if the suspend triggered the issue or something else ...
I will monitor this issue.

Comment: Boot back into your previous custom kernel and see if the wifi works again.

Comment: Custom kernel was not working as well. However I managed to fix the issue ... for now (see my edit in the original post).

Comment: On this laptop It is soldered on the board.
I have completely replaced Windows by Ubuntu.